# Returning data from Google's Geocoding API with PHP curl

Tags: php, angularjs, curl, google-geocoding-api

This question is similar to another one answered, however the solution in that case was to use a country code, which is not feasible for this particular use, as the address is being provided by the user through an input field (so a country may not be provided).

Here is the content of my current request

**Request coming from AngularJS:**

```
function getCoordinatesFromApi(address) {
            addressApiResponse = $http({
                url: 'php/coordinates.php',
                method: 'get',
                params: {
                    address: address
                },
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            });
            return addressApiResponse;
        }
```

**Request handled in PHP:**

```
$api_maps = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/';
$address = urencode($_GET['address']);
$api_key = 'API_key_here';
$url = $api_maps . 'api/geocode/json?address=' . $address . '&key=' . $api_key;
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo ($curl_response);
```

When this is called, I consistently get back a valid response with status: 200, but data is an empty string.

I've checked the validity of the $url being build in PHP and it is ok, accessing that url directly in the browser displays a valid API response with data.

I've also tried **using Angular's $http** method and that too returns a valid response from the API:

```
function getCoordinatesFromApi(address) {
            addressApiResponse = $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&key=API_key_here');
            return addressApiResponse;
        }
```

For some reason, it's ony the curl method that does not behave as expected. Has any one dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that echo ($curl_response); return nothing even if status is 200, it's because it's encoded JSON!

Please try this :

```
$decodedresponse = json_decode($curl_response);

//send me what var_dump return so I can hellp you accessing the array!
echo var_dump($decodedresponse);


//You would use as an array DEPENDING ON HOW THE ARRAY IS BUILD OF COURSE
echo $decodedresponse['response']['lat'];
echo $decodedresponse['response']['long'];
```

Comment: I've tried this now but it doesn't seem to work either. With your changes in place, data now returns 'NULL' and nothing else.

Comment: $decodedresponse = json_decode($curl_response);

//send me what var_dump return so I can hellp you accessing the array!
echo var_dump($decodedresponse);
  Just this ?

Comment: Yes, that is all I get back. My php now looks like this:
    `$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    // echo ($curl_response);
    $decodedresponse = json_decode($curl_response);
    echo var_dump($decodedresponse);`

And the entire response I get back in my JS when making this call is:
    `config:{method: "GET", transformRequest: Array(1), 
    transformResponse: Array(1), jsonpCallbackParam: "callback", 
    paramSerializer: ƒ, …}
    data:"NULL↵"
    headers:ƒ (d)
    status:200
    statusText:"OK"
__proto__:Object`

Comment: hum I'm not into JS so can't help for this.

Answer (score -1):

try again

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
```

Comment: **[You should not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software)**. It could be a security risk! [Here is how to get the certificate bundle if your server is missing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)